# Swift - Eureka / Adding margin to left and right of ButtonRow

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am using Eureka for creating a form.

Added ButonRow to the form but can't add margin (maybe padding?) to the left and right of the button for make it smaller and centered.

How can I achieve that?

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2IFu.jpg)

Comment: can you share a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to make it more centered and smaller actually: [image link](https://imgur.com/8Qf6Q5b)

Comment: added image link @ReinierMelian

Comment: ok I will let you know my findings

Answer (score 2):

```
.cellSetup { cell, _ in
    cell.indentationLevel = 1
    cell.indentationWidth = 12
    cell.contentView.layoutMargins.right = 20
}
```